# How do I find out the year last April, specifically the 1st of the last April in php

Tags: php, date

In php I need to find the year that last April is in. This is so I can do a mysqli query from that date. The date I want is the 1st of last April. The problem is that you might be in the next month, or next year. For instance last April could be in 2015 and you are in January 2016. Ok this is the code I have tried, but obviously it doeesn't work.

```
    $datestring='first day of last april';
$date=date_create($datestring);
echo nulldate_full($date->format('Y-m'));
```

I have tried a lot of variations of this and nothing seems to work. I have also search for an answer on stackoverflow also, without much success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, although it requires [some lines of code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8245d4a5d55fd0dd23f0a64ec2b8bfd15c617f94):

```
// first of April this year
$april_this_year = date('Y-04-01');

// current date
$today = date('Y-m-d');

// current year
$year = date('Y');

// if April in this year is yet to come   
if ($april_this_year >= $today) {
    // then it was previous year
    --$year;
}

// show it
echo $year;
```

Please note that the above code will consider "last April" to be this year if we are currently in April.