# PHP - How to get the last occurrence of a month?

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I need to define the start and end dates of a tax year, but I don't seem to find anything with relative formats which gives me something like this:
`strtotime('6th day of last april')` (doesn't work)

The thing is that if today is for example the 10th of May, then the year is the same; however, if we are in February, the year must be the past one.

I assume there is a better way to determine the year rather than by using if statements? But I can't find this case in the dates related documentation.

---

EDIT: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876394/how-do-i-find-out-the-year-last-april-specifically-the-1st-of-the-last-april-in), there seems to be no direct syntax for it and some code is required.

Comment: It's because in programming languages there is no concept of a financial year, you have to do it by yourself.

Comment: What are the rules to calculate tax year in your country in plain English? Your attempted `strtotime()` expression doesn't make it too clear.

Comment: The problem is not about tax years, it's about php date expressions; the tax year is just a practical example to explain the issue. The issue is getting the date in a past month, which may be in the current year, or (year -1)

Answer (score 0):

If the year is missing in a date expression, Datetime takes the current year for the year. However, the date you want to create contains a condition. If the created date is in the future, 1 year should be deducted. This cannot be solved with the relative DateTime formats. As an alternative to the if construct, I can only offer the ternary operator:

```
$date = ($date = date_create('Apr 06')) < date_create('Today') 
  ? $date 
  : $date->modify('-1 Year')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

A posible solution would be:

```
$date=strtotime('Apr 06');
if($date > time()) $date = strtotime("-1 year", $date);
```